# How to make pylint enforce docstrings for all functions and methods in a repository

Tags: python-3.x, pylint, pylintrc

Pylint missing-docstring seems to ignore some functions and private methods in classes.

How can I make pylint enforce that all functions and methods have to have docstrings in a certain repository?

one option I've found is to disable ignoring of private functions:
`no-docstring-rgx='a^'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use: `no-docstring-rgx=__.*__`
this should take into account all functions.
By default is: `no-docstring-rgx=^_`
Which skips private methods